# Scala not working in Windows 10 from command line and PowerShell

Tags: scala, powershell, command-line, windows-10

After installing Scala in Windows 10 and trying to run it from command line or PowerShell:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin>scala

i'm getting the following in return:

```
\scala\bin\scala.bat) was unexpected at this time.
```

I realize that the installation path is a bit unfortunate (contains space) but i thought they've solved this problem already versions ago.

Any ideas how to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to be posted here:
https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7821

The last comment fixes the issue:

"The modification must be done on each .bat file under the "scala\bin" directory, which consists of scala.bat, scalac.bat, scaladoc.bat, and scalap.bat.

At the bottom of every file you will find these two subroutines, ie. ":add_cpath" and ":set_home"

In **:add_cpath** change

```
if "%_TOOL_CLASSPATH%"=="" (
set _TOOL_CLASSPATH=%~1
) else (
set _TOOL_CLASSPATH=%_TOOL_CLASSPATH%;%~1
)
```

into

```
if "%_TOOL_CLASSPATH%"=="" (
set _TOOL_CLASSPATH="%~1"
) else (
set _TOOL_CLASSPATH="%_TOOL_CLASSPATH%;%~1"
)
set _TOOL_CLASSPATH=%_TOOL_CLASSPATH:~1,-1%
```

(notice the quotation marks)

And in **:set_home** change

```
set _BIN_DIR=
for %%i in (%~sf0) do set _BIN_DIR=%_BIN_DIR%%%~dpsi
set _SCALA_HOME=%_BIN_DIR%..
```

into

```
set _BIN_DIR=
for %%i in ("%~sf0") do set _BIN_DIR=%_BIN_DIR%%%~dpsi
set _SCALA_HOME=%_BIN_DIR%..
```

(here notice the quotation marks as well)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to add path to Scala bins to system Path variable and run it as "scala" from anywhere? Alternatively, you can run Scala. sh using Git Bash or use Bash command prompt from Windows Subsystem for Linux.